# Multiple authentication providers: /j_spring_security_check and social login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a problem with my security xml configuration. I am not able to access the username and password from my login form for local login (social login works fine)

**In very short:**
When the user submits the login form, the first emergence into my code is in UserDetailService

```
public SpringSecurityLocalUser loadUserByUsername(final String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

where userId is an empty String. Thus no way to authenticate. How do I get access to username and password? Adviice would be much appreciated

---

**UPDATE**
I am now quite confident the issue is due to my need for a seond authentication provider. (i.e., one local as well as one social). But not sure how to configure this

---

**security_applicationContext.xml**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

 <security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="appAuthenticationEntryPoint">

  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/flow-entry.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/flow-jobpostdata.html" access="permitAll()"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/flow-jobpostdata_anydegree.html" access="permitAll()"/>
   <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll()"/>
  
 
  <!-- Adds social authentication filter to the Spring Security filter chain. -->
  <security:custom-filter before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="socialAuthenticationFilter"/>
  <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="SecurityAuthFilter"/>
 
 
 </security:http>

<!-- authentication manager and its provider( social provider deals with social login & local user provider deals with form login ) -->
 <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider ref="socialAuthenticationProvider"/>
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="localUserDetailService"/>
 </security:authentication-manager>

 <bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
  <constructor-arg ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="socialUserDetailService"/>
 </bean>
  
  <bean id="appAuthenticationEntryPoint"
   class=" jake.delivery.controller.welcome.AppAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
 
 <bean id="failureHandler"
   class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
  <constructor-arg name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/services/accessdenied"/>
 </bean>
  
 <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
   id="SecurityAuthFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
  <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler"/>
  <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_security_check"/>
  <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices"/ </bean>

 <!-- social login filter which is a pre authentication filter and works for /auth service url -->
 <bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
  <constructor-arg name="authManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
  <constructor-arg name="userIdSource" ref="userIdSource"/>
  <constructor-arg name="usersConnectionRepository" ref="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"/>
  <constructor-arg name="authServiceLocator" ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"/>
  <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler"/>
 </bean>

 <!-- inmemory connection repository which holds connection repository per local user -->
 <bean id="inMemoryUsersConnectionRepository"
   class="org.springframework.social.connect.mem.InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository">
  <constructor-arg name="connectionFactoryLocator" ref="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"/>
  <property name="connectionSignUp" ref="connectionSignUp"/>
 </bean>

 <!-- service registry will holds connection factory of each social provider-->
 <bean id="appSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry"
   class="jake.delivery.controller.welcome.AppSocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
  <constructor-arg>
   <list>
    <ref bean="facebookAuthenticationService"/>
   </list>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean> 

 <bean id="facebookAuthenticationService"
   class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
  <constructor-arg name="apiKey" value="xxxxxxx"/>
  <constructor-arg name="appSecret" value="xxxxxx"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource"/>

 <bean id="connectionSignUp" class="jake.delivery.controller.welcome.AppConnectionSignUp"/>





</beans>
```

**UserDetailService implementation**

```
package jake.prototype2.service.loginservices;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import jake.prototype2.model.structure.SSm;

public class LocalUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {



public LocalUserDetailService()
{
    SSm.getLogger().debug("init" );
}

@Override
@Transactional
public SpringSecurityLocalUser loadUserByUsername(final String userId) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
{

                SSm.getLogger().debug(this.getClass().getName()+"\n\n\n\n\n  I don't do anything yet\n\n\n\n\n\n",new Exception());
                SSm.getLogger().debug("userId" + userId);
                                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("  fork me sideways  ");

}
```

}

Stacktrace.
Although there has been no exception, I captured the stacktrace for reference purposes.

> java.lang.Exception
>       at jake.prototype2.service.loginservices.LocalUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(LocalUserDetailService.java:32)
>       at jake.prototype2.service.loginservices.LocalUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(LocalUserDetailService.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.loadUserByUsername(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144)
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: spring saves username and password received as parameter j_username and j_password in its context, then call your method to load user only by username and then check the returned entity (instanceof UserDetails).

Comment: Thanks! But how do I get access to the un pw paramater values before my instance of UserDetails or in my instance of UserDetails?

Comment: You can check received credentials in `authenticate`method in `ProviderManager`class.

Comment: oh...actually, now I understand your point. So my question is wrong. My question should be why userId is an empty string

Comment: my provider is for social and does not get called for local

Comment: So, I think the problem is in the parameter's name in your login form.

Comment: It's not. I think it is to do wiith my needing a second aithenticationProvider for local login. BUT...I don't want to take up too much of your time. You have already been very helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124422/discussion-between-andolsi-zied-and-jake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually to do with requiring multiple authentication providers.

It turns out that only one line of configuration was missing:

```xml
<!--  authentication manager and its provider( social provider deals with social login & local user provider deals with form login ) -->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="socialAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="localUserDetailService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="jake.delivery.controller.welcome.CustomAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="auService" ref="auService" />
</bean>
```

I needed to add an additional line to `authentication-manager` for `customAuthenticationProvider`.